# prevent an object inside div from reloading

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, object, bootstrap-tabs

I have three bootstrap 2.0 tabs and one of the tabs href is a div which opens an external website using object. Everytime I switch to this tab, the website reloads. Is there a way to prevent the object (external website) reload when I switch to this tab ? Or may be there is a better  approach to show a dynamic external website ?

```
<li  id="myli"">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#myframe" id="mybtn">
    <span id="editor-label-results" class="voc-bigmode-only">StackOverFlow</span>
    <i class="icon icon-th-list voc-smallmode-only"></i>
    </a>
</li>

<div id="myframe"  ...>
    <object type="text/html" data="http://stackoverflow.com" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px" ></object>   
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about using an iframe instead of an object tag?  Also, your tab markup is incomplete.  You need tab-pane classes, a tab-panel, etc.  See the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) documentation for examples, and consider updating to the newest version of Bootstrap (3.3.0 I believe)

Comment: @Kathy. Yes I have tried iframe and it is the same result. And I do have tab-pane etc. I think it just got omitted in the code above by mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @Kathy. I stand corrected. There was a problem in my code. iframe works. Thanks.